# How to start jw player automatically?

Tags: embed, jwplayer, autostart

Here is my embed code:

```
<embed width="576" height="432" flashvars="&amp;
    file=kgalive&amp;
    streamer=rtmp://5.77.33.107/kga" wmode="opaque" 
    allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true"
    quality="high" name="player" id="player" style=""
    src="player.swf" autostart="always" 
    type="application/x-shockwave-flash"/>
```

It works, but my player will not start automaticaly while opening the webpage. What should I do to start my player automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically:

```
<embed width="576" height="432" flashvars="&amp;
    file=kgalive&amp;
    streamer=rtmp://5.77.33.107/kga" wmode="opaque" 
    allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true"
    quality="high" name="player" id="player" style=""
    src="player.swf" autostart="always" 
    type="application/x-shockwave-flash"/>
```

Needs to be:

```
<embed width="576" height="432" flashvars="&amp;
    autostart=true&amp;file=kgalive&amp;
    streamer=rtmp://5.77.33.107/kga" wmode="opaque" 
    allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true"
    quality="high" name="player" id="player" style=""
    src="player.swf" autostart="always" 
    type="application/x-shockwave-flash"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it should be

```
autostart="true"
```

I do it this way:

```
<object id="mediaplayer" width="100%" height="100%" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="jwplayer/player.swf" bgcolor="#000000" name="mediaplayer" tabindex="0">
  <param name="allowfullscreen" value="true">
  <param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always">
  <param name="seamlesstabbing" value="true">
  <param name="wmode" value="opaque">
  <param name="flashvars" value="netstreambasepath=<URLHERE>&id=mediaplayer&autostart=true&repeat=always&shuffle=false&controlbar.position=none">
</object>
```